# Trying to login to cassandra's console (cqlsh) and it rejects me

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-2.0, cqlsh

I was trying to set up the user authentication for cassandra when I had the following problem.

First I have updated the `cassandra.yaml` with:

```
authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator
```

then created the system_auth keyspace with a replication_factor of 3 as:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_auth WITH REPLICATION =  { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3};
```

Then re-ran cassandra with the command:

```
bin/cassandra
```

Then after all that, I proceeded and made sure to repair my node(s) with (though I am not sure if I understand why this is important/necessary):

```
nodetool repair
```

Even after doing all of those steps cassandra/java yells at me with:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tscobb/Documents/BM/apache-cassandra-2.0.5/bin/cqlsh", line 2044, in <module>
    main(*read_options(sys.argv[1:], os.environ))
  File "/home/tscobb/Documents/BM/apache-cassandra-2.0.5/bin/cqlsh", line 2030, in main
    display_float_precision=options.float_precision)
  File "/home/tscobb/Documents/BM/apache-cassandra-2.0.5/bin/cqlsh", line 480, in __init__
    cql_version=cqlver, transport=transport)
  File "/home/tscobb/Documents/BM/apache-cassandra-2.0.5/bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip/cql-1.4.1/cql/connection.py", line 143, in connect
  File "/home/tscobb/Documents/BM/apache-cassandra-2.0.5/bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip/cql-1.4.1/cql/connection.py", line 59, in __init__
  File "/home/tscobb/Documents/BM/apache-cassandra-2.0.5/bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip/cql-1.4.1/cql/thrifteries.py", line 157, in establish_connection
  File "/home/tscobb/Documents/BM/apache-cassandra-2.0.5/bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip/cql-1.4.1/cql/cassandra/Cassandra.py", line 465, in login
  File "/home/tscobb/Documents/BM/apache-cassandra-2.0.5/bin/../lib/cql-internal-only-1.4.1.zip/cql-1.4.1/cql/cassandra/Cassandra.py", line 486, in recv_login
cql.cassandra.ttypes.AuthenticationException: AuthenticationException(why='org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.UnavailableException: Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM')
```

Honestly, at this point I am not sure how to proceed. If anyone has any ideas, it would be greatly appreciated.

I am running cassandra 2.0.5 in a Ubuntu vm. Not sure if that helps at all.

Also, when I run:

```
nodetool status
```

The following comes up:

```
nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address Load    Tokens  Owns   Host ID                              Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  1.57 MB  256     100.0%  37ae1d4c-0df5-43d2-9593-4603ac68c34a  rack1
```

Comment: How many nodes do you have in your cluster?

Comment: how do I find out that info?

Comment: Post the output of `nodetool status`.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 I posted it! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3
```

As you only have one node in your cluster, setting a replication factor of 3 would be your problem.  Here is an [article that describes replication in Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/cluster_architecture/replication).  You should give it a quick read through.  One part in particular applies here:

> When replication factor exceeds the number of nodes, writes are
>   rejected, but reads are served as long as the desired consistency
>   level can be met.

```
Cannot achieve consistency level QUORUM
```

Cassandra computes "Quorum" as (replication_factor / 2) + 1.  So if you have a replication factor of 3, then 2 nodes need to be running for your consistency level to be met.

Basically, set your replication factor back down to 1, and you should be fine.

Comment: I am a little confused about this, everywhere I read, I need to set up my replication factor for more than 1 when changing authorization stuff, why is it that I need the opposite? I am slightly confused.

Comment: also, sorry if this is really obvious to you, but how do you specify the replication factor in the cassandra.yaml file? What I do to change that is revert the authenticator to AllowAllAuthenticator and then change it in cqlsh...I guess from your suggestion my approach is a little silly

Comment: The reason for setting the replication_factor to something other than 1, is that if the one node holding the system_auth keyspace goes down, you won't be able to get into your other nodes.

Comment: If you are using DSE-Cassandra, there should be a spot in your .yaml for `auth_replication_options:` and then `replication_factor`.  If not, then resetting your authenticator and authorizer would be the way to go.

Comment: The datastax docs are a bit confusing about this.  They say NOT to use a replication factor of 1, but clearly you have to if you only plan on having 1 node ever.  http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secConfSysAuthKeyspRepl.html